# Test Entities in Azure Storage using Java and Mocking tests

Tags: java, azure, mockito, cloud, azure-storage

It's been a long time, i was searching for a way to test Entities(Add properties, values..) in files in **Azure Table Storage**. For example after adding a property to an entity, i want to check if the property is added succesflly or not by tests(Perfectly using **Mock** tests), but the problem is that i don't want to test in **Azure Storage** in **Cloud** or in an **Emulator**, i want simply test it localy.
I don't fin a way to do that.

```
TableServiceClient tableServiceClient  = mock(TableServiceClient.class);
TableClient tableClient = mock(TableClient.class);
TableEntity tableEntity = mock(TableEntity .class);
properties is a Hash map of properties and values
when(tableEntity.addProperties(properties)).thenCallRealMethod();

when(tableEntity.getProperty(Mockito.anyString())).thenCallRealMethod();
doNothing().when(tableServiceClient.createTableIfNotExists(Mockito.anyString());
when(tableServiceClient.getTableClient(Mockito.anyString()).thenReturn(tableClient);
```

Comment: You mean by mocking `CloudTableClient` and related classes? What prevents you from doing that?

Comment: I want to test TableServiceClient, but this class needs a connection String which allows this class to connect the server, but i don't want it to do that, i think i had to use Mockito, but Mockito also connect to the server when i build the TableServiceClient

Comment: You need to post your actual code if you want any advice. Form your comment, I guess you are trying to use `TableServiceClientBuilder` instead of mocking `TableServiceClient`. I don't observe any connection to any server when I properly mock `TableServiceClient`. One way to do this: `TableServiceClient tsc = Mockito.mock(TableServiceClient.class);`

Comment: @Lesiak i just added the code, the idea is that i want to create a TableClient and added it to TableClientService, then create TableEntity and added it to TableClient, and finally added properties to this TableEntity

Comment: 1. It is ok that you added test code, but still cannot comment without seeing the method under test. 2. calling real method on a mock only makes sense if it implemented in terms of other methods. TableEntity has properties field which will be uninitialized if you do that. Luckily TableEntity is a simple object with no dependencies, don't use a mock for that